# How to have Log secondary Axis along with Linear one in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh, multiple-axes

How does one puts a Log secondary Y axis to a chart with a main Y linear axis ?

I've tried this :

```
import numpy as np
import bokeh as b
import bokeh.io
from bokeh.models.formatters import *
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, LogAxis, DataRange1d


TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

x = np.arange(100)
y1 = np.arange(100)
y2 = np.arange(100)**3
p3 = figure(
    tools=TOOLS, active_scroll="wheel_zoom",
    plot_width=800, plot_height=500,
    title = "TEST")

p3.line(x, y1)

p3.extra_y_ranges = {"log": DataRange1d()}
p3.add_layout(LogAxis(y_range_name="log"), 'right')

p3.line(x, y2, color='#FF0000', y_range_name="log")

show(p3)
```

But it doesn't work [on my browser] : the left axis is shown only if I zoom, and it appears as a linear axis...

Am I missing something or should I fill a bug ?

Answer (score 3):

Currently `bokeh==0.12.10` has problem with log and a linear axis when represented at same time.
The bug has been reported. [Github Bug Report.](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7217)